# Return table in original form after INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

i have an SQL that innner joins a table to give me required results, but the returned dataset (C#) is different as it now renames column names or increment with 1.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [dbo].[ComputerState] as a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerState] as b ON a.ServiceName != b.ServiceName
WHERE a.State = 5 and b.State = 5
AND a.ServiceName IN (
 SELECT [ServiceName] FROM [dbo].[ComputerState]
)
```

The problem is it returns on row like such,

```
[ComputerName, ServiceName, ComputerName1, ServiceName1]
[server, service, server2, service2]
```

Can i get it to return like the original table format

```
[ComputerName, ServiceName]
[server, service]
[Server2, service2]
```

i could ofcourse remove the INT 1 from column names, but would be nice if i could avoid this.

Comment: You could double query on your output to select the left and the right part of the output table and `UNION` them together to 1 table.

Comment: not being a SQL expert, how would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a UNION on your output you can move the results below each other:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.*
FROM [dbo].[ComputerState] as a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerState] as b ON a.ServiceName != b.ServiceName
WHERE a.State = 5 and b.State = 5
AND a.ServiceName IN (
 SELECT [ServiceName] FROM [dbo].[ComputerState]
)

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 1 b.*
FROM [dbo].[ComputerState] as a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerState] as b ON a.ServiceName != b.ServiceName
WHERE a.State = 5 and b.State = 5
AND a.ServiceName IN (
 SELECT [ServiceName] FROM [dbo].[ComputerState]
)
```

P.S. To be honest this might lead to a performance increase, since the `INNER JOIN` will be done twice. Their might be a more efficient matter, but I'm not certain how it could be done best.

Comment: This works thx, for now but as you mention not good for longterm, ill investigate maybe creating a function (try at least)

Answer (score 0):

You can select `a.*` instead of `*`. Also, you might want to use the `WITH TIES` option of `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES a.*
FROM [dbo].[ComputerState] as a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ComputerState] as b ON a.ServiceName != b.ServiceName
WHERE a.State = 5 and b.State = 5
AND a.ServiceName IN (
 SELECT [ServiceName] FROM [dbo].[ComputerState] 
)
```

However, using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is usually a bad idea anyway. And I'm not aware what you actually intend to query (accessing three times the same table is usually a bad idea).

Comment: Then it only returns a single ROW, need to keep output but in a single table with values in multiple rows instead of a single row.